# Windows Phone 8: Reading XML from Web

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

As part of a project i am working on i am trying to load this XML page (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115) into my Windows Phone 8 application and save the a number of the values as variables.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 professional and VB.net.

So far i have searched and tried a number of ways just trying to save one variable to start with but i am unable to get it to read.

this is what i have so far

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Private XMLHANDLE As WebClient

Dim lang As String

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait Or SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape


    Dim XML As String = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115"
    XMLHANDLE = New WebClient()
    XMLHANDLE.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(XML))

    AddHandler XMLHANDLE.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf XMLHANDLE_DownloadStringCompleted
    AddHandler XMLHANDLE.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf XMLHANDLE_DownloadProgressChanged
End Sub


Private Sub XMLHANDLE_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)

End Sub


Private Sub XMLHANDLE_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.[Error] Is Nothing AndAlso Not e.Cancelled Then
        Dim resultElements As XElement = XElement.Parse(e.Result)


        lang = resultElements.Element("language").Value
        Console.WriteLine(lang)
    End If

End Sub
```

My code keeps Finding a null value exception on this line

```
lang = resultElements.Element("language").Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` looks only over direct children of current element, so you can't get `language` element that simple.

Try that:

```
lang = resultElements.Element("channel").Element("language").Value
```

Or using `Descendants` method:

```
lang = resultElements.Descendants("language").First().Value
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that, only just getting my head arround XML thanks for quick answer, wont let me mark as answer yet but ill do it as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Just another Question say i wanted to get the value of  the city Property from this <yweather:location city="New York" region="NY" country="United States"/> how would i go about it?