# XML and ":" issue

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, windows-phone

second post today after first was answered i have run into another issue!

Basically i have the below code. i know that it is correct apart from one thing, the ":" character is not allowed and throws up an exception, does anybody know the best way to get around this?

```
   location = resultElements.Element("channel").Element("yweather:location").Attribute("city").Value
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your XML, please. `yweather` is a namespace so you have to use `XNamespace` instance within your query. However, I cannot show you an answer without the XML you're trying to query data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you have exactly the same XML input as described in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988649/windows-phone-8-reading-xml-from-web).

Within first element there are two namespaces declared:

```
<rss xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" 
     xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
     version="2.0">
```

You have to declare `XNamespace` instance for them first:

```
Dim yweather = XNamespace.Get("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0")
```

And you have to use that namespace when you're querying elements that start with `<yweather:` or `<geo:`. So use `yweather + "location"` instead of `yweather:location`:

```
Dim location = resultElements.Element("channel") _
                             .Element(yweather + "location") _
                             .Attribute("city") _
                             .Value
```